# Django: How can I have static and dynamic views live in the same server directory?

Tags: django

I have some HTML views that are static, and some that are dynamic, and I want them to serve out of the same directory. For instance, `/` would be a dynamically generated view, but `/about` would very much be static.

This sort of also applies to the `favicon.ico` file, plus all the little files like `robots.txt` and so on. I want them to live side by side with my dynamic views, but that seems like it would require a combination of tedious `urls.py` and `.htaccess` remappings...

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Ever heard of the [Flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/) app?

Comment: You can do this by configuring your containing web server to serve URLs according to some pattern as flat files and only falling back to WSGI or however you're including your Django app when they're not recognized. This is of course easiest if your static files can be confined to a particular pattern of URLs in a way that your webserver configuration likes.